# Bash script to run Celery Flask app and make a request

Tags: bash, flask, celery

I want to write a bash script to open RabbitMQ, initiates Flask and Celery and then make requests. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Start RabbitMQ
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin 
rabbitmw-server 

#Start Flask
export FLASK_APP=run.py 
flask run 

#Start Celery
celery -A run.celery worker --loglevel=info

#Send my request
curl -X PUT -d "data=mydata" http://localhost:5000/user/5
```

How can I write it properly to works?
When I have to do it without a bash script I have to open 4 different terminals: 
* In 1 I run RabbitMQ
* In 2 I run flask
* In 3 I run Celery
* In 4 I make my request

Comment: I forgot to comment that i am using a Mac

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible for bash commands to continue before the result of the previous command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398388/is-it-possible-for-bash-commands-to-continue-before-the-result-of-the-previous-c)

Comment: In production, it's better to use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) or similar.